# JQuery Mobile Hide Drop Down LIST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, as the title suggests; I am trying to figure out how to hide a drop down list. I am using JQuery mobile features. When I try to hide it, it's still visible.

Here is my drop down code:

```
<select name="areaName" id="areaName" data-inline="true">
                    <option value="0">Select an Area</option>
                    <?php
                        include ("partials/connectDb.php");

                        $goverChoice = $_POST['goverName'];

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM area_table WHERE governorate = '$goverChoice';";
                        $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query))
                        {
                            # code...
                            $aId = $row['a_id'];
                            $aName = $row['name'];
                            echo "<option value='{$aId}'>{$aName}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
</select>
```

And this is my JS code:

```
document.getElementById("areaName").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: In jQuery $("#areaName").hide() should do it.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/8hu90e9x/3/

Comment: @TeaTime I tried it, didn't work either. Don't understand why

Comment: @DrydenLong It didn't work for me. Note that I am using JQuery Mobile too. Though I am not sure if it makes really a difference :&

Comment: Maybe you dont have integrated jquery or the elements arent there yet if you fire the code.

Comment: @TeaTime I didn't get that, but this is what I included in the <head> tag:

Comment: @TeaTime <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: Your jquery libraries are probably not getting loaded. Do you have js errors in your inspector?  Add https to your jquery references.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle? That might help track down the issue...

Comment: can u provide us a fiddle with the problem mentioned above? would help alot